# Change all the .txt files to .md files in a certain folder

Tags: terminal, file-conversion

Is there a Terminal command or something like that to batch rename files in a certain folder? Basically I want to change all the files that have a .txt as a file type, and change it to .md (for markdown). Is this possible? I am comfortable using the Terminal, being a developer, so don't hold back on solutions. :)

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do the following in Terminal:

> find . -iname "*.txt" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%\.txt}.md"' {} \;

This will recursively rename all .txt files in the current directory to .md.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do not use *zsh* as your default shell, you can still use *zmv* in a temporary shell:

```
zsh -c 'autoload zmv;$0 $@' zmv -w '*.txt' '$1.md'
```

Recursively:

```
zsh -c 'autoload zmv;$0 $@' zmv -w '**/*.txt' '$1$2.md'
```

Note: The `-n` option is handy for testing.

*zmv* is described in the `zshcontrib` manpage, and the full glob syntax is described in the `zshexpn` manpage in the “Filename Generation” section.

Comment: This does seem like a shorter syntax, umm... Could you give me a little bit of what this zmv or zsh command does? Thanks. :)

Comment: With `-w`, each wildcard gets put into a positional parameter (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) to be used in the new name; without `-w` you must include parentheses to delimit the extent of the text that is matches and placed in the positional parameters. So, not using `-w` may make it a bit more obvious: `zsh -c 'autoload zmv;$0 $@' zmv -n '(*).txt' '$1.md'` renames all `*.txt` files (in the current directory) to end in `.md` instead of `.txt`; `zsh -c 'autoload zmv;$0 $@' zmv -n '(**/)(*).txt' '$1$2.md'` does likewise in the current directory and all subdirectories.

Comment: Oh OK! Well thanks a lot! I used the other one but will keep this in mind for the future. :)